# "SendHeader called multiple times" error while sending too fast via gRPC

Tags: go, grpc

I tried to use duplex gRPC streams and some times (when server response is too fast) I get an error "SendHeader called multiple times" in stream.Recv()

How to get rid of it? What am I doing wrong? Or, maybe, gRPC does not support so fast send/reply cases?

Minimal code example below. Error is getting sometimes where ~5000 send and ~5000 responses processed in 400-500 ms (or about it).

Server starts goroutine on each request (via stream, so ~5000 goroutines). All of them send responses. No one error is showed on the server.

```
srv, _ := grpcClient.DuplexStreamCall(context.Background())

// channel to prevent send more than <100> messages to stream
diffCh := make(chan struct{}, 100)
sendWg := sync.WaitGroup{}
sendWg.Add(1)

// Sending goroutine
go func() {
    defer sendWg.Done()

    for _, item := range someTasks {
        // put "task" into the channel buffer
        diffCh <- struct{}{}

        err := srv.Send(&proto.ItemRequest{
            Item: item,
        })
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }

    err := srv.CloseSend()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}()

rcvWait := sync.WaitGroup{}
rcvWait.Add(1)


// recieving goroutine
go func() {
    defer rcvWait.Done()

    for {
        req, err := srv.Recv()
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            // HERE i get "SendHeader called multiple times" error
            // which is
            // ErrIllegalHeaderWrite = status.Error(codes.Internal, "transport: SendHeader called multiple times")
            panic(err)
        }

        doSomeWork()

        // release channel buffer
        <-diffCh
    }
}()

sendWg.Wait()
rcvWait.Wait()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was is concurrent sending responses on the server-side. According to documentation - server can not Send() in concurrent, I had to user mutex with Send() from server.